# How to encode JSON output in PHP mysqli ?

Tags: php, arrays

my PHP code look like this

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");
    global $connect;

    if (isset($_POST['login']) )
    {
        $login = $_POST['login'];

        $sql   = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE login='$login'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $login_db    = $row['login'];
                $real_namedb = $row['real_name'];
                $email_db    = $row['email'];
                $dept_db     = $row['dept'];
                $division_db = $row['division'];

                $output= array('messages' => '1', 
                                                'login' => $login_db,
                                                'real_name' => $real_namedb,     
                                                'email' => $email_db, 
                                                'dept' => $dept_db, 
                                                'division' => $division_db
                               );
                echo json_encode($output);
                exit();
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            $output = array('messages' => '2', 'login' => 'wrong credentials from PHP code!');
            echo json_encode($output);
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
            exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output = array('messages' => '3', 'login' => 'No post data');
        echo json_encode($output);
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">  
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
                <td>Email : </td>
                <td><input type ="text" name="login" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    

        <p><input type ="submit" name="Submit" value="DISPLAY"> </p>             
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code above display JSON output like this

```
{"messages":"1","login":"ID0111","real_name":"NAME HERE","email":"mail@mail.com","dept":"IT","division":"MDO"}
{"messages":"1","login":"ID0112","real_name":"NAME HERE2","email2":"mail@mail.com","dept":"IT","division":"MDO"}
```

My question is how to modify PHP code above to make JSON output display like this ? What I mean is single login has multiple "messages" value

```
{
    "login":"ID0111",
    "real_name":"NAME HERE",
    "messages":
                [
                    {
                        "refno":"1234",
                        "email":"mail@mail.com",
                        "dept":"IT",
                        "division":"MDO"
                    },
                    {
                        "refno":"1345",
                        "email":"mail2@mail.com",
                        "dept":"IT",
                        "division":"MDO"
                    },
                ]
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: You `exit` within the loop. I don't see how you get 2 lines in output.

Comment: because he has encoded json two times

Answer (score 1):

Create to two arrays,in first array give login,realname and in second array give refno,email,dept,division then merge the second with first array and then use json_encode().

```
  <?php

    $result =array();
    $message=array();

    $result['login'] ='ID0111';
    $result['real_name'] ='NAME HERE';
    $message['refno'] ='1234';
    $message['email'] ='mail@mail.com';
    $message['dept'] ='IT';
    $message['division'] ='MDO';
    $result['message'] =$message;

    echo json_encode($result);


  ?>
```

Comment: How to combine both array into single output ? can you update the code in your answer ? thanks